# Azure windows self-hosted agent with docker installed

Tags: azure, docker, kubernetes, azure-devops-self-hosted-agent

We are trying to develop Azure windows self-hosted to run Azure pipelines.

However, these agents are deployed on **kubernetes**. And we want these agents to be able to use docker for build/push operations. meaning we need docker inside docker.

Is it possible to install docker on these windows self-hosted agents ?

Comment: What do mean by the windows self-hosted agents? Azure VM? Or Devops agent?

Comment: self-hosted agent pools can be either linux or windows, so I'm trying to install docker into a self-hosted agent (windows). 
and as I said these agents (linux and windows) are deployed as services on kubernetes

Comment: You could install docker on the agent machine directly, do you get any issue during installation?

Comment: @CeceDong-MSFT Yes installing docker cause problems specially I want to give non-root user access to docker socket ?

Comment: How about creating the docker group and adding your user as [this documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/linux-postinstall/) mentioned? - container: ubuntu image: ubuntu:16.04 options: '--group-add docker' (https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-agent/issues/2056#issuecomment-454897571).

Answer (score 2):

You need to set up a self-hosted agent in Azure Pipelines to run inside a Windows Server Core (for Windows hosts), or Ubuntu container (for Linux hosts) with Docker. Detailed steps you may refer to the following link:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/docker?view=azure-devops

Comment: OP are saying, they need "docker inside docker". I have just created a working self-hosted agent (linux ubuntu) using the information from the link you provided in your answer, but the matter is that when we have `docker-compose` jobs **inside a pipeline.yaml** then we get the error `An error occurred trying to start process 'docker-compose' with working directory '/azp/_work/1/s/tst/GatewayIntegrationTests/bin/Release/net6.0'. No such file or directory` because there is no docker inside the dockered agent...

Comment: ...any ideas? Is that even possible, how do the Microsoft-hosted agents provide any of the docker commands inside a pipeline? Because there, that works just fine.